# Difference between $\tt rand()$ and $\tt randn()$ in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, signal-analysis

1. `rand()` is for "Uniformly distributed pseudorandom numbers"

   I generate two `rand` arrays, and then use the cross-correlation (`xcorr2`) and the normalized cross correlation (`normxcorr2`) as follows:

   ```
   a = rand(512,512);
   b = rand(512,512);
   c = xcorr2(a,b);
   figure;surf(c);shading flat;axis tight;
   d = normxcorr2(a,b);
   figure;surf(d);shading flat;axis tight;
   ```

   The results are as follows:

   [image: xcorr2]  [image: normxcorrs]

   in which there is strong correlation in the `xcorr2()`.
2. `randn()` is for "Normally distributed pseudorandom numbers"

   The same as the above:

   ```
   a = randn(512,512);
   b = randn(512,512);
   c = xcorr2(a,b);
   figure;surf(c);shading flat;axis tight;
   d = normxcorr2(a,b);
   figure;surf(d);shading flat;axis tight;
   ```

   and the results are:

   [image: xcorr2]   [image: normxcorr2]

Then, my question is why there is apparent difference of `xcorr2()` for the two random data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that `rand()` has an output range of $[0,1]$, and therefore you have a constant in both $a$ and $b$ in the first example. The other function `randn()` generates an output with zero mean. The constants are correlated. Try

```
a = -0.5 + rand(512,512);
b = -0.5 + rand(512,512);
```

or

```
a = rand(512,512);
b = rand(512,512);
a = detrend(a,'constant');
b = detrend(b,'constant');
```

and see if that is more like what you would expect...

Comment: Thank you, you are right. it is the cross correlation of the two dc signals.